# gprof does not run whole program and displays incorrect call counts

Tags: c++, gprof

I am trying to learn to use gprof and wanted to test the speed difference between the same function returning a copy and returning a pointer to a new-ed object. I then discovered that gprof does not seem to actually run the whole program as it takes way less time than running the program on its own and also it does not accurately show how many times a certain function should have been called.

This is my program:

```
#include "heap.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    typedef SorterMAX<int> SRT;

    random_device rnd_device;
    mt19937 mersenne_engine(rnd_device());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9999);

    auto gen = std::bind(dist, mersenne_engine);
    vector<int> vec(10000000);
    generate(begin(vec), end(vec), gen);

    SRT s;

    Heap<SRT> h(vec, s);

    while (! (h.size() == 0))
    {
    std::cout << h.size() << std::endl;
        h.top_with_copy();
    }
}
```

and this the class it uses:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

/// minheap sorter
template <class N>
class SorterMIN
{
public:
    typedef N NODE;
    bool operator()(const NODE& n1, const NODE& n2) const
    {
    return (n1 <= n2);
    }
};


/// maxheap sorter
template <class N>
class SorterMAX
{
public:
    typedef N NODE;
    bool operator()(const NODE& n1, const NODE& n2) const
    {
    return (n1 >= n2);
    }
};


template <class SORTER>
class Heap
{
public:
    typedef typename SORTER::NODE NODE;

    Heap(std::vector<NODE>& v, SORTER& s)
    : data(v), sorter(s)
    {
    for (auto node_itr = v.begin()+(v.size()/2); node_itr != v.begin()-1; node_itr--)
    {
        sift_down(node_itr - v.begin(), v, s);
    }
    data = v;
    _size = v.size();
    }

    NODE top_with_copy()
    {
        NODE top = *(data.begin());
    std::cout << "copy\n";
        data[0] = *(data.end()-1);
        data.pop_back();
        sift_down(0, data, sorter);
        _size--;
        return top;
    }

    // NODE* top_with_pointer()
    // {
    //  NODE* top = new NODE(1);
    //  std::cout << "pointer\n";
    //  top = &(*(data.begin()));
    //  data[0] = *(data.end()-1);
    //  data.pop_back();
    //  sift_down(0, data, sorter);
    //  _size--;
    //  return top;
    // }

    int size()
    {
    return _size;
    }

    void sift_down(int node_index, std::vector<NODE>& v, const SORTER& s)
    {
    int left_child_index= 2*node_index+1;
    int right_child_index = 2*node_index+2;
    int to_swap_index;
    if (right_child_index <= v.size()-1)
    {
        if (s(v[left_child_index], v[right_child_index]))
        {
        to_swap_index = left_child_index;
        }
        else
        {
        to_swap_index = right_child_index;
        }
    }
    else if (left_child_index <= v.size()-1)
    {
        to_swap_index = left_child_index;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    // if sorter returns false, then order is incorrect
    if (!s(v[node_index], v[to_swap_index]))
    {
        NODE tmp = v[node_index];
        v[node_index] = v[to_swap_index];
        v[to_swap_index] = tmp;
        sift_down(to_swap_index, v, s);
    }
    }

private:
    std::vector<NODE>& data;
    SORTER& sorter;
    int _size;
};
```

Now, I would expect `top()` to be called 10000000 times. But in the gprof output it says it was called thrice.

```
0.00      2.07     0.00        3     0.00     0.00  Heap<SorterMAX<int> >::top_with_copy()
```

The commands I sued are these:

```
g++ heap.hpp; g++ -pg heapteast.cpp; gprof a.out gmon.out > analysis_returncopy
```

Some of the output of the program shows that `top()` is indeed called more than thrice:

```
9882766
copy
9882765
copy
9882764
copy
9882763
copy
9882762
copy
9882761
copy
9882760
copy
9882759
copy
9882758
copy
9882757
copy
9882756
```

What is going on here? How can I make gprof run the whole program and display correct numbers?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the expression `!(h.size() == 0)` could also be expressed as `h.size() != 0`. In this case it probably doesn't matter, but with operator overloading in C++ the two otherwise equivalent expressions could do very different things.

Comment: gprof is a sampling profiler (although instrumentation can be added).  This means that it interrupts your program at regular intervals and records where the code is executing.  Small quick to execute functions can easily be missed.

Comment: In previous runs it displayed the call count correctly though. Then I changed something and could not get it to "work" anymore afterwards.